# Ionic popup alert not closing properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The first alert verifies whether the entered password corresponds to the user's password
If it does, then opens another alert where the user change the password if he has entered the same password in both fields
And finally, the third alert will open if it has successfully changed the password

The problem occurs if I click Cancel in the second alert or after confirming the third alert
After that, I'm not able to click on anything inside the app until I unload and restart the same application

So I guess the problem occurs because the alert is not closed properly

Here is my code:

```
$scope.changePass = function () {
$scope.newitem = {}

var myPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
  template: '<input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="newitem.password">',
  title: 'Insert your password',
  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Cancel' },
    {
      text: '<b>Confirm</b>',
      type: 'button-positive',
      onTap: function(e) {
          if (!$scope.newitem.password) {
            console.log("preventing default");
            e.preventDefault();
          } else {
            if($scope.newitem.password == $scope.user.password) {
              $scope.new = {}
              var newPass = $ionicPopup.alert({
                template: '<input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="new.newpass"><br><input type="password" placeholder="Repeat password" ng-model="new.repeatpass">',
                title: 'Insert your new password',
                scope: $scope,
                buttons: [
                  { text: 'Cancel' },
                  {
                    text: '<b>Confirm</b>',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function(e) {
                        if (!$scope.new.newpass) {
                          console.log("preventing default");
                          e.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                          if (!$scope.new.repeatpass) {
                            $scope.new.newpass = "";
                            console.log("preventing default");
                            e.preventDefault();
                          } else {
                            if ($scope.new.newpass == $scope.new.repeatpass) {
                              $scope.user.password = $scope.new.newpass;
                              var uri = "http://someLink" + $window.localStorage.id;
                              $http({
                                  method: 'PUT',
                                  url: uri,
                                  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"},
                                  data: $scope.user
                              }).success(function() {
                                var succesResponse = $ionicPopup.alert({
                                  title: 'Ok',
                                  template: "Password has changed"
                                });
                                succesResponse;
                                e.preventDefault();
                              });
                            }
                            else {
                              $scope.new.newpass = "";
                              $scope.new.repeatpass = "";
                              e.preventDefault();
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              });
            }
            else {
              $scope.newitem.password = "";
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          }
      }
    }
  ]
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question

Namely, the solution is to close the first alert before I open the second alert
But before I open second alert, it is necessary to have a timeout to close the first alert properly

```
myPopup.close();
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.new = {}
    var newPass = $ionicPopup.alert({...});
}, 500);
```